# How to define source port of outgoing TCP socket in Dart

Tags: dart

I want to build a TCP connection `sourceAddress:x`-> `host:port`, how can I set `x` in dart?

The docs only describe `Socket.connect(dynamic host, int port, {dynamic sourceAddress, Duration? timeout}`, where it's not possible to define the local port `x`.

Appending the port to the `sourceAddress` variable here throws an invalid address error. Also `RawSocket` does not accept a local port parameter. I don't want to use a ServerSocket here, because I actually need to define the ports of both sides. To my understanding, this is only supported in dart for UDP 'connections':

```dart
var s = await RawDatagramSocket.bind(
        sourceAddress, x,
        reusePort: true);
s.send(...)
```

At least in python this is possible (from https://idea.popcount.org/2014-04-03-bind-before-connect/), where it's called bind-before-connect.

```py
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(sourceAddress, x)
s.connect(host, port)
```

Do you know if and how a similar result can be achieved in dart?